# Linear algebra classic, Farkas lemma application

Tags: linear-algebra

$A \in M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$.
Farkas' lemma says exactly one of the following holds:

(a) there exists some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $x \geq 0$, such that $Ax = b$

(b) there exists some vector $p \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $p^TA \geq 0$ and $p^Tb < 0$.

where $0$ means all-zero vector of dimension $n$ and comparing two vectors means comparing all components of the vectors.

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$. My task is to derive from Farkas’ Lemma that exactly one of the following holds:

(a) $0 \in$ convex.hull$\{ x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m \}$

(b) there is a row vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $yx_i > 0$ for $i = 1, . . . , m$.

I tried but cannot proceed. From the first you can deduce that $x_i$ are linearly dependent  but then i am stuck since i don't see how to apply the lemma :(

Comment: The notation $\,A\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}\,$ for $\,m\times n\,$ can be confusing imo. Perhaps it'd be better $\,A\in M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)\,$. Also, it must be $\,x\in\Bbb R^n\,$. Does $\,x\ge 0\,$ means all this vector's components are non-negative?

Comment: @DonAntonio I edited. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: I edited. Do you have some ideas what a better title would be. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\Mat{\mathrm{Mat}}\def\R{\mathbb R}$Let $A \in \Mat_{n+1,m}(\R)$ given by 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_m\\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
and $b \in \R^{n+1}$ by $b = \binom{0_n}1$. Then, by Farkas,

either (a) for some $\lambda\in\R_{\ge 0}^m$, we have $A\lambda = b$, which is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i x_i = 0$, $\sum_i \lambda_i = 1$, that is $0 \in \mathrm{conv}\{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}$.

or (b) for some $y = (\bar y, y_{n+1})^t \in \R^{n+1}$ we have $y^TA \ge 0$ that is $\bar y^t x_i + y_{n+1} \ge 0$ for each $i$, and $y^t b = y_{n+1} < 0$. So this holds, if for each $i$ $\bar y^t x_i \ge -y_{n+1} > 0$.