# Deducing Farkas' lemma from its convex hull formulation (full details inside)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove the converse direction of this question: [Linear algebra classic, Farkas lemma application](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399994/linear-algebra-classic-farkas-lemma-application). To quote explicitly:

Assume:

> For every $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$, exactly one of the following holds:
>
> (a) $0 \in$ convex.hull$\{ x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m \}$
>
> (b) there is $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\langle y,x_i \rangle > 0$ for all $i$.

I want to prove:

> $A \in M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$.
>   Exactly one of the following holds:
>
> (c) there exists some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $x \geq 0$, such that $Ax = b$
>
> (d) there exists some vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $y^TA \geq 0$ and $y^Tb < 0$.

---

**Approach**

Define $x_1,...,x_{n+1}$ to be the columns of $A$ and $-b$.

if (b) holds then we have $A^T y >0$ and $y^Tb<0$ so (d) holds, even with strict positiveness.

So **assume (a), and we want to prove that (c) or (d) hold**.

This suffices since easily we cannot have both (c) and (d) instantaneously.

We have $p_1,...,p_{n+1} \geq 0$ with sum $1$ such that $A \begin{pmatrix}
           p_{1} \\
           p_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           p_{n}
         \end{pmatrix}=p_{n+1}b$.

If $p_{n+1} \neq 0$ then we divide by it and get (c), so assume $p_{n+1}=0$.
Thus we have some probability vector $p \geq 0$, $p_1+...+p_n = 1$ with $Ap = 0$. Here I'm stuck: how can I deduce (c) or (d)?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ we have that

$$A^Ty = (\langle x_1, y\rangle, \dots, \langle x_n, y\rangle).$$

Hence, in order for $(d)$ to hold we must show that there is some $y\in\mathbb R^n$ with $\langle b, y\rangle< 0$ and $\langle x_i, y\rangle \geq 0$ for all $i$.

Every equation $\langle x_i, y\rangle \geq 0$ defines a halfspace $H_i$ whose boundary is a hyperplane through the origin, given by $\langle x_i, y\rangle = 0$.
If $(b)$ does not hold, it means that the intersection of the open halfspaces $\text{int}(H_i)$ with the open halfspace given by $\langle b, y\rangle > 0$ is empty.

The intersection of $n$ closed halfspaces through the origin is either a half cone or a line.
If it's a half cone $C$, the existence of $y$ with $\langle b,y\rangle <0$ is clear from the fact that $\langle b, y\rangle > 0$ does not intersect $C$.

Finally, a line is only possible if at least two of the halfspaces share boundaries -- in other words, if $x_i=-\alpha\,x_j$ for some $i \neq j$ and $\alpha >0$.
But this would mean $(a)$ holds, which contradicts our hypotheses.

Comment: The intersection of closed halfspaces can also be just the origin, in which case we cannot have (d) since there is no nonzero $y$ with $\langle x_i,y \rangle \geq 0$. But then there must be a subset of the halfspaces that has as the intersection a line. Right?

Comment: The intersection of $n$ closed halfspaces though the origin in $\mathbb R^n$ cannot be just the origin. However, the intersection of $n+1$ closed halfspaces through the origin in $\mathbb R^n$ can.

Comment: I had written if $x_i = -x_j$, but actually I just meant to say one is a negative scalar multiple of the other -- they don't need to have the same size, only opposite directions.